# .ForEach() not applying while normal for loop is

Tags: c#, foreach

Im trying to use the .ForEach() method to apply an action to a list but the action is not being applied. Here is an example of what I'm doing:

```
floatList.ForEach(f => f = 0);
```

This is not applying the action I'm doing within the lambda expression. When I do this same thing using a normal for loop, it executes correctly. I've tried looking up threads that explain the differences between the ForEach() method vs a normal foreach or for loop but I' m still not sure on why it is not executing the command I'm putting in within the .ForEach() method.

Comment: Post the full code that is not working for you

Answer (score 3):

The problem with assigning to `f` inside a lambda is that `f` is passed by value. Any changes to `f` itself are not reflected in the actual value in the collection or `IEnumerable`. `foreach` loop would have the same issue, except `f` would not be assignable. Regular `for` Loop, on the other hand, has a way to operate on the collection directly, so it is free of this problem.

Note that although changing the item itself is not allowed, you can call its mutable methods, and the changes would stay:

```
floatList.ForEach(f => f.SetSomeValue(0));
```

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't realize it didn't modify the list directly, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are expecting exactly.  I guess you would have to show us your "normal loop" to compare.

But your code is actually equivalent to:

```
foreach(float readOnlyF in floatList)
{
    float f = readOnlyF;
    f = 0;
}
```

It basically assigns a value to a local `f` variable, which you assign to, but that is immediately thrown away after the iteration completes.  It doesn't try to write into the `floatList`, if that's what you were expecting.

Comment: Thanks for that deconstruction of what it does, that helps me understand it a lot better. I just didn't realize the extent to which it used a local variable for each entry in the list.